# Extract string from another Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, extract

I would like to extract this string :

**QFTe8wTWv41c8lMWf8wTTn**

from this string containing 2 '.' characters :

**20140221.QFTe8wTWv41c8lMWf8wTTn.113151592514**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var res = yourstring.split(".")[1];
```